# Handling key and mouse listeners

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, mouselistener

How can I handle mouse and key listeners at the same time in JPanel?
I tried to add that mixed listener, and set JPanel's setFocusable(true):

```
class MyListener implements MouseListener, KeyListener {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

But when key is pressed mouse listener don't listen actions, how to handle that?

Comment: AWTEventListener .....

Comment: Are you asking why the mouse methods are not called when you press a key?

Comment: @NESPowerGlove Yes! That is what I am asking

Comment: Well, it's because that's not the way it works. Pressing a key on a component that has focus and has a KeyListener added to it will cause one of the KeyListener methods to be executed on the EDT, not the mouse methods, because those are for mouse events that occur in a similar fashion.

Comment: "listening at the same time" does not make much sense. Events are enqueued and handled sequentially. Even if an event comes in when you are executing code of a listener, it should be enqueued and handled later.

Comment: Are you saying no listener works, or is it that the key listener does work but it blocks the mouse listener?

Comment: For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Comment: @Troveldom Yes, when key and mouse is being pressed, only keyPressed is called but not mousePressed! I have been searching answer for my problem for four days and haven't found answer yet! So, is it possible or not?